# Use yarn instead of npm in an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have to use `yarn` instead of `npm`.
Is it possible to do this in an Azure pipeline?
This is what I've got but it doesn't work.

```
steps:
- task: UseNode@1
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  inputs:
    version: '18.x'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'yarn install' 
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyModule'
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'yarn install'
    verbose: true

# Npm task can't publish pre-release therefore edit the package.json
# $(Build.BuildNumber) is actually the pipeline name set on the first line -- that's Azure YML for you.
- ${{ if not(or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'))) }}:
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm version' 
    inputs:
      workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyModule'
      command: custom
      customCommand: version prerelease --preid=$(Build.BuildNumber)

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'yarn run build' 
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyModule'
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'yarn run build'
    verbose: true
  
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    contents: |
       ReactWebsites/*
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Copy project files (MyModule/*)'


- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm publish' 
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyModule'
    command: publish
    publishRegistry: useFeed
    publishFeed: 'MySoftware'
```

The `yarn install` step fails saying `Unknown command: "yarn"`.

I've tried adding

```
- script: npm install --global yarn
  displayName: "install yarn"
```

but that fails saying `npm ERR! File exists: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.19.1/x64/bin/yarnpkg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML sample, you are using Yarn install command in the NPM task.

This is the cause of the issue. NPM task only can be used to run NPM command instead of Yarn command.

To solve this issue, you need to run the Yarn install command in the script/powershell/bash/command line task.

For example:

```
steps:
- script: 'yarn install'
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyModule'
  displayName: 'yarn install'
```

Then it can work as expected.

[image]

For more info, you can refer to this doc: [Use Yarn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/customize-javascript?view=azure-devops#use-yarn)

On the other hand, you can also use the Yarn task in the Extension: [Yarn](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tasks to use yarn instead of NPM in your yaml file. I show you an example, it downloads yarn in the build agent and then use it to install the packages:

```
- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-installer-task.YarnInstaller@3
    displayName: "Use Yarn 1.x"

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@3
    displayName: "Yarn"
    inputs:
       projectDirectory: ${{ path }}
       arguments: "--frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 300000"
```